# How to apply arrow style to curved arrow?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have an arrow style which works fine for straight arrows. The only purpose of the style is to enlarge the arrowheads, so if there is a simpler way to do this do let me know. Anyhow, when I apply the style to a curved arrow, no arrowhead is rendered. The MWE provided shows the curved arrow with a default head, but I would much like to somehow apply my arrow style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal, thick, minimum
    height=1cm}, >=stealth, start chain]
    
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
    {\arrow[scale=2,>=stealth]{>}}},postaction={decorate}]

    \node[list,on chain] (A) {$A_1$};
    \node[list,on chain] (B) {$A_2$};
    \node[list,on chain] (C) {$A_3$};
    \node[list,on chain] (D) {$A_4$};
    \node[list,on chain] (E) {$A_5$};
    \node[on chain] (F) {NULL};
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
    \draw[arrow, dashed] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
    
    %%%%---I would like the arrowhead style applied here---%%%%
    \draw[->,>=stealth, thick] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) to [bend left=60] (D.one west);
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (D.two), \p2 = (D.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (E);
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (E.two), \p2 = (E.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (F);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % <---
                bending,
                chains,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[angle=30:7pt, bend]}}, % <---
 start chain = going right,
 list/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
               rectangle split horizontal, 
               rectangle split empty part width=1.5em, 
               draw, thick, minimum height=1cm, 
               on chain}, 
               ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={list}]
\node   (A) {$A_1$};
\node   (B) {$A_2$};
\node   (C) {$A_3$};
\node   (D) {$A_4$};
\node   (E) {$A_5$};
    \end{scope}
\node [on chain] (F) {NULL};
%
\draw   (A.two north |- A.two east) edge (B) 
        (B.two north |- C.two east) edge[dashed] (C)
        (C.two north |- C.two east) edge (D)
        (D.two north |- D.two east) edge (E)
        (E.two north |- E.two east) edge (F);
\draw[semithick]
        (B.two north |- B.two east) edge[bend left=45] (D.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**  added details of arrows heads size. All arrows are the same, if the they have the same head lengths:

[image]

- How to determine arrows heads size is described in section *16.3.1 Size* in the *TikZ & PGF manual*, pp 194 -- 197. It is part of you `tikz` installation or you can found it CTAN (use google to find it).
- If arrows are bendend, than for aligning arrows head to bended line serves option `bend` and `flex`. Their use are described in the section *16.3.8 Bending and Flexing*, pp 202 -- 204.
- For both features you need to load libraries `arrows.meta` and `bending`

Comment: Thanks! But the *arrowhead* of the curved arrow is still smaller than the others, I'd like it to be the same size as the other arrowheads.

Comment: @John, all arrows head are equal if the thickness of arrows lines are the same or the lenghts of arrows heads are the same. See edited answer

Comment: Ah, I did something silly when I copied your solution previously. I noticed if I increase the ```7pt``` to something like ```14pt``` then the arrow heads change as well. This is what I want. I'm quite new to Tikz, can you explain why changing this value affects all arrowheads? Thanks!!

Comment: @John, see edit of answer. I add some basic information, where you can find description of `arrows.meta` and `bending library.